# How to statistically describe the spatial relationship among the variables

Tags: modeling, autocorrelation, spatial, spatial-interaction-model

I have identified the points of forest loss (lat-long), these points are categorized by year (like 2001, 2002 etc.). I have created another raster that has pixel values of distance from the nearest road. Created another such raster for the market where forest wood is sold. I see that there is a relationship among them just placing forest loss points (lat-log) onto the market distance raster, road distance raster. Relationship is like all forest loss pixel tends to be near the road and market.

Now how, statistically, I can measure the scenerio that (majority of) **forest loss pixels/points locations tend to be near the location of road/market etc**.

Answer (score 1):

Why not build a matrix representative of the correlation structure of your pixels for each year.

To do so, let us start with something like,

$\boldsymbol{v} = (v_1,...,v_n)^{'}$

where $\boldsymbol{v}$ is a $n \times 1$ vector of $0$ or $1$ values, with $1$ standing for a position exhibiting a forest loss.

$\boldsymbol{W} = [w_{ij} (d_{ij})] \equiv [e^{-\gamma d_{ij}}]$ or $\equiv [d_{ij}^{-\gamma}]$ or something else which is distance-based. Note that distances can be geographic, economic, road-based, etc...

where $\boldsymbol{W}$ is a spatial weight matrix, entrywise specified to relate the distance-based strength of interaction between any position $i$ and $j$ of your space. And then you could compute the correlation between $\boldsymbol{v}$ and itself spatially lagged. I mean, computing

$\rho(\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{v}) = \frac{E(\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{v}) - E(\boldsymbol{v})E(\boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{v})}{\sigma_{\boldsymbol{v}}\sigma_{\boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{v}}}$

with $E(\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{v})$ simply standing for the average of $((\boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{v})_{1} \times \boldsymbol{v}_1,...,((\boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{v})_{n} \times \boldsymbol{v}_n)^{'}$, $E(\boldsymbol{v})E(\boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{v})$ trivially is the product of each vector average and $\sigma$ their respective standard deviation.

If $\rho(\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{v})$ is positive, it would mean that all forest loss pixels tend to be close one to another. If $\rho(\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{v})$ is negative, it would mean that all forest loss pixels tend to be close to non-loss pixels. If it is null, the space of correlation is not the one you chose (geographic, economic, etc...).

Note that the result you'll get will highly depend on the correlation structure you involve (your choice of $\boldsymbol{W})$. Also note that I use binary values, but it would be exactly the same with continuous ones, i.e. between $0$ and $1$.

Since you have done this for each year, you can see the evolution of $\rho$ over time. So i should have written all preceding variables with a $t$ index, e.g. $\boldsymbol{v}_{t}$, excepted for $\boldsymbol{W}$ that we can suppose constant for all years, i.e. $\boldsymbol{W}_{t} = \boldsymbol{W} \ \forall \ t$.

Now if you need to have a full statistical consideration, you also need to compute the p-values related to each $\rho_t$.

Furthermore, note that I do not involve time in the correlation structure since you only ask for "spatial relationship".

Comment: Thank you for your cordial effort indeed! Could you dispel my hesitation since I need to substatiate/refute that location of the forest loss pixels tend to be near the location of the nearest of the wood market or road but your statistic , as stated in the answer, gives relation among the location of forest loss pixels location.

Comment: Another thing that I just found which worth mention. You mentioned `v` is a binary matrix but your formula tells to get the average of this `v` i.e. `E(v)`

Comment: Exactly. And if $\rho(\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{v})$ > 0 it means that your $1$s are close to each other in the chosen space (idem for the $0$s), if it is negative, it means that your $0$s are close to your $1$s. There is actually no problem with taking the sample mean of a boolean vector.

Comment: Any question @SIslam ?